# Pgfplots decimal separator on colorbar for 3D plots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm wondering if I can change the number format of the colorbar for a 3D plot. Unfortunately I don't find any answers in the pgfplots manual.
Do you have an idea?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   /pgf/number format/.cd,
        use comma,
        1000 sep={},
        colorbar,
         colorbar style={
        xticklabel={Leistungsbilanz},
    },
            xlabel={$\vartheta_i$ [°C]},
    ylabel={$\dot{W}_R$ [W]},
    zlabel={Leistungsbilanz [W]},
]
    \addplot3+ [mark=none,
    domain=20:180,
    domain y = 0:5500,
    samples = 20,
    samples y = 8,
    surf,
    shader = interp] {y-1600-1.1*(x-20)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: The colorbar is, concerning the number format, no different from axes (to the best of my knowledge), so you can use the manual describing the latter.

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't seem to work. I have edited the original post and added th example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
tick label style={
  /pgf/number format/.cd, use comma, 1000 sep={},
},
colorbar,
xlabel={$\vartheta_i$ [°C]},
ylabel={$\dot{W}_R$ [W]},
zlabel={Leistungsbilanz [W]},
]
\addplot3+ [mark=none,
domain=20:180, domain y = 0:5500,
samples = 20, samples y = 8,
surf, shader = interp,
] {y-1600-1.1*(x-20)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 3D surface plot with colorbar]

Comment: alrigth, thanks!